# Looking for a generic, fast, low-memory algorithm to output N-out-of-M combinations of an array without repetitions

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have an array with players

```
$players = array('A','B','C','D','E','F');
```

and i want to get every possible 3 way finishing.

```
1st 2nd 3rd
A   B   C
A   B   D
...
C   A   B
C   B   A
...
F   D   E
F   E   D
```

I have some permutation algorithm but it must be something else since in permutation there is 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 combination and here is only 6 * 5 * 4

Comment: You say you have some permutation algorithm. If you want help with that I would suggest that you post the code for it.

Comment: The answer to your code, would be 6*5*4, as the rest of the places dont matter..

Comment: You guys do realize that he wants the permutations, not just the count, right?!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudo-code to print your 3 out of 6 combinations without repetition:

```
for i = 1 to 6
  for j = 1 to 6
    if (j != i)
      for k = 1 to 6
        if (k != i && k != j)
          print(A[i], A[j], A[k])
        end if
      next k
    end if
  next j
next i
```

For the general k-of-n case see: [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: And what if he wants 4 out of 7? Or 2 out of 5? Or 5 out of 10? Or 1 out of 4? Or 6 out of 6? Or 3 out of 8? Or 2 out of 4? Or 6 out of 8? Or 4 out of 5?

Comment: Just adapt the code to it. The pseudo-code just addresses the given problem. No more, no less.

Comment: What I mean is, even though this solves the specific problem, it doesn't at all scale and is not reusable under other circumstances.

Comment: I completely agree. But why solve problems that maybe just don't exist? Changing the 6 to array length shoudn't be a problem. And it's stated quite clear in the question that he needs only 3 out of N (first 3 places of a competition). Else he could have asked the more generic question: "Looking for a generic, fast, low-memory footprint algorithm to output N-out-of-M combinations of an array without repetitions". ;-)

Comment: he seems to have listened to your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given your permutation algorithm, you can use it in two steps to get the desired permutations.

First, let's consider the following mapping. Given input as `A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 ... An`, a value `b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 ... bn` means select `Ai` if `bi` is 1 and not if it is 0.

With your input, for example:

```
0 0 1 1 0 1 -> C D F
0 1 0 0 1 1 -> B E F
```

Now your algorithm can go as follows:

- Take `n` as the number of elements (in your case 6) and `m` as the number you want to choose from.
- Construct the following sequence:

  ```
  0 0 0 ... 0 1 1 1 ... 1
  \____ ____/ \____ ____/
       V           V
     n - m         m
  ```
- Get all permutations of the above sequence and for each:

  - Find the `m` elements that are marked in the sequence
  - Get all permutations of those `m` elements and for each:

    - do whatever you want!

Comment: Im not 100% sure but as i figured out what i want is called combination and not permutation

Comment: In your example, `A B C` and `C A B` are distinguished. This is permutation. If you just want 3 of them, regardless of their order (combination), then you have to skip the inner `get_permutations`.

Comment: It already exists in C++. It is called [`next_permutation`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/next_permutation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not finding all permutations of 6 elements.

Your problem is to choose 3 elements, and than check its permutations.

The number of combinations = C(6,3)*3! = 6! / 3! = 6*5*4.

C(6,3) - for choosing 3 elements out of 6. (No matter the order)

3! - for ordering the 3 chosen elements.

This is the exactly number of combinations you should get. (and you do)

However, you can use your permutation algorithm to get all permutations of the 6 elements.
Than, just ignore the last 3 elements, and remove duplicates from the result.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think you have the correct amount of possible permutations here. You choose only 3 players among the 6 players array. So for the first player, you have 6 possibilities, for the second player you have 5 possibilities, and for the third player, you have 4 possibilities.

If you decide to have 4 players at the end instead of having 3, the possible amount of permutations would be 6*5*4*3, and so on.

I hope my math is not too old!